# Explanation of draw in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

Could someone tell me what calls the draw method in libgdx?

```
@Override
public void draw (Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
//whatever goes here
}
```

I don't know if I can explain this well, but my question is that after implementing the draw method, who constantly calls it? In the Actor class, for example:

```
public void draw (Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
}
```

I'd guess, though I'm not sure, that there is some code somewhere that is in charge of calling on each render or something.

Comment: @Alex K thanks for adapting to English

Comment: Render method is called from render thread that runs in a background.

Comment: Veljko thaks for answering

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer.-**

Stage calls the Draw method of all its Actors.

**Long Answer just for completeness.-**

Stage calls Draw method of its (root) Group.

[Stage.java -L118](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.java#L118)

```
public void draw () {
    Camera camera = viewport.getCamera();
    camera.update();

    if (!root.isVisible()) return;

    Batch batch = this.batch;
    if (batch != null) {
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        root.draw(batch, 1);
        batch.end();
    }

    if (debug) drawDebug();
}
```

And root Group calls its drawChildren method.

[Group.java -L56](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Group.java#L56)

```
public void draw (Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    if (transform) applyTransform(batch, computeTransform());
    drawChildren(batch, parentAlpha);
    if (transform) resetTransform(batch);
}
```

And this is the method who calls all child Actors draw method.

[Group.java -L66](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Group.java#L66)

```
protected void drawChildren (Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    parentAlpha *= this.color.a;
    SnapshotArray<Actor> children = this.children;
    Actor[] actors = children.begin();
    Rectangle cullingArea = this.cullingArea;
    if (cullingArea != null) {
        // Draw children only if inside culling area.
        float cullLeft = cullingArea.x;
        float cullRight = cullLeft + cullingArea.width;
        float cullBottom = cullingArea.y;
        float cullTop = cullBottom + cullingArea.height;
        if (transform) {
            for (int i = 0, n = children.size; i < n; i++) {
                Actor child = actors[i];
                if (!child.isVisible()) continue;
                float cx = child.x, cy = child.y;
                if (cx <= cullRight && cy <= cullTop && cx + child.width >= cullLeft && cy + child.height >= cullBottom)
                    child.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
            }
        } else {
            // No transform for this group, offset each child.
            float offsetX = x, offsetY = y;
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            for (int i = 0, n = children.size; i < n; i++) {
                Actor child = actors[i];
                if (!child.isVisible()) continue;
                float cx = child.x, cy = child.y;
                if (cx <= cullRight && cy <= cullTop && cx + child.width >= cullLeft && cy + child.height >= cullBottom) {
                    child.x = cx + offsetX;
                    child.y = cy + offsetY;
                    child.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
                    child.x = cx;
                    child.y = cy;
                }
            }
            x = offsetX;
            y = offsetY;
        }
    } else {
        // No culling, draw all children.
        if (transform) {
            for (int i = 0, n = children.size; i < n; i++) {
                Actor child = actors[i];
                if (!child.isVisible()) continue;
                child.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
            }
        } else {
            // No transform for this group, offset each child.
            float offsetX = x, offsetY = y;
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            for (int i = 0, n = children.size; i < n; i++) {
                Actor child = actors[i];
                if (!child.isVisible()) continue;
                float cx = child.x, cy = child.y;
                child.x = cx + offsetX;
                child.y = cy + offsetY;
                child.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
                child.x = cx;
                child.y = cy;
            }
            x = offsetX;
            y = offsetY;
        }
    }
    children.end();
}
```

Comment: thanks you, your response is very good thank you for your time, but my question would be who does the draw and renders at a level above, and I think after reading your posting was looking for other sites and I think I found the answer I imagined, An ApplicationListener is called when the is created, resumed, rendering, paused or destroyed. All methods are called in a thread that has the OpenGL context current. You can thus safely create and manipulate graphics resources.